# How to dump PostgreSQL database structure (each object in separate file)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I'm using Postgres 8.4 and I want to dump database structure (no data). Is is possible to get each object (table, view, function etc.) in a separate file, NOT EVERYTHING in one file???

Comment: You can check my answer in this other post from SO :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58869245

Comment: https://github.com/omniti-labs/pg_extractor does this

Answer (score 1):

Use newer version of [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) (at least version 9.1) and you can dump to a directory using --format=directory

> This will create a directory with one file for each table and blob
>   being dumped

Comment: The separate files are only used for the data, with `--schema-only` the complete DDL is still compressed into the TOC. (could be possible to extract the parts by applying a script, though)