# PostgreSql , extract schema objects DDL to separate SQL file

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I want to export all objects DDL to separate file example (`table_a_create.sql`, `view_b_create.sql`, `trigger_c_create.sql`, `table_contraints.sql` ...)

I was trying with `pg_dump` but it only exports to one file for the whole schema.

I read some questions about this on stackoverflow but still not enough for my requirement

Ex: [How to dump PostgreSQL database structure (each object in separate file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281087/how-to-dump-postgresql-database-structure-each-object-in-separate-file)

Is there any way to do it? I'm using Windows

Comment: What do you consider to be an "object"? Is a column part of a table, or a separate object? What about contraints? Or triggers?

Comment: @Bergi I mean table, view, constraint, trigger definition only. No data, no function need

Comment: You can try with the `-t` option but this is not safe as the objects that this table depends on will not be dumped so there is no guarantee that the table definition can be successfully restored.

Comment: https://github.com/omniti-labs/pg_extractor does this

Answer (score 2):

If you are on the client machine, you can put this in a SQL script (e.g. export_plpgsql.sql) :

```
\pset tuples_only on
\pset footer off
\set QUIET on
\pset format unaligned
\set QUIET off

SELECT '\echo ''* Export '||(CASE proKind WHEN 'f' THEN 'Function' ELSE 'Procedure' END)||' : '||proName||''''
       ||chr(10)||'\copy (SELECT pg_get_functiondef('||p.oid||')) TO '''||:'export_path'||'/'||upper(proName)
       ||(CASE proKind WHEN 'f' THEN '.fct' ELSE '.prc' END)||''' WITH CSV;' as export_routine
FROM pg_proc p
WHERE proNamespace = (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspName = lower(:'schema_name'))
ORDER BY proName;
```

and call it using 2 arguments : schema_name and export_path, for example :

```
psql -U my_ -d my_db -v schema_name=my_schema -v export_path=C:/temp/export_PG -f export_plpgsql.sql > C:\temp\export_plpgsql.gen.sql
```

This will generate a script containing all the exports command for your plpgsql routines, e.g.

```
\copy (SELECT pg_get_functiondef(51296)) TO 'C:/temp/export_PG/my_procedure.prc' WITH CSV;
```

Last step : run the generated script

```
psql -U my_ -d my_db -f C:\temp\export_plpgsql.gen.sql
```

It will generate a .prc file for each procedure and a .fct file for each function.
NB: You may have to refine the script as you can have other kind of functions (proKind) in pg_proc view.